# How to get ID field in form through internal name in SharePoint

Tags: client-object-model, client-side-rendering

I'm learning Sharepoint 2013 . I have a new form to add data . In that form i have a web part add javascript . In that script i want add code custom this form and i want get ID through internal name of field but i can't find function in SP.FormCollection or SPClientTemplate So ,

> How can i get ID field in form through internal name (Javascript)

I was try but it failed

```
var value = SP.FormCollection.get_item ()
```

Comment: Could you please share what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a field called `Level` at your `newform` page and you need to get its ID, in this case ,I think it's easier to get the ID by its `title name` rather than `internal name` as the following

Try to add script editor , then add the following code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function getID()
{
alert($("input[title='Level']").attr('ID')); 

}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getID"); 

</script>
```

This code will return the Control ID of the Level field .